# How to Properly Generate a Monero Brain Wallet?

Tags: security, stealth-address, mnemonic-seed, opsec

I remember reading somewhere, I think it was fluffypony mentioning one could use for example words from a letter to a loved one seed for a Monero wallet. But from playing with https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html I realized that it is not possible to enter just any text in the mnemonic seed; it just doesn't accept improperly formed mnemonics, apparently. And even if I had 24 words chosen from the official word list, I would still not know what checksum word to add at the end... (I haven't tried generating a brain wallet in monero-wallet-cli yet, but if there is a way, please let me know.)
Is there a way to create one's own mnemonic?

On the other hand, I am assuming that the hexadecimal field does accept anything, since it *is* the private spend key. So maybe the way to go would be to choose one's own preferred passphrase, take SHA256 of the passphrase and enter it in field 2. Is that how it should be done?

Obviously, one should be very careful choosing such a passphrase, but I am thinking that brain wallets in Monero shouldn't be as dangerous as in Bitcoin simply due to the inherent time consuming operation of scanning the blockchain and trying to decode every single output for the corresponding stealth address. I am guessing that a decent computer should take at least a few seconds for each brain wallet, so that compiling a huge list of brain wallets and monitoring them is unfeasible. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: If they know your address, they can check the brain wallet quite quickly. Most setups don't think about address security, since it's meant to be public.

Comment: Also see http://monero.stackexchange.com/q/1519/255

Comment: @PyRulez: I am assuming you mean if someone knows my private keys they can lookup my balance quickly. That's true, but the point is the attacker would have to try a multitude of guesses to figure out my private keys in the first place. How can they do that? That would take scanning the entire blockchain to check for a balance, which is prohibitively costly. Alternatively, they could just check the new transactions, but even then it is not so cheap since there is a lot of hashing to be done, and no way to organize things in a hash table to make lookups faster, as is possible in Bitcoin.

Comment: No, I'm saying that if they have your *public keys*, they don't need to go through the blockchain to break it.

Comment: they only need to crack the stealth address to be able to spend the moneroj.

Comment: @PyRulez: I think I finally got your point: if you *already know* the target address, then indeed it is easy to check if your guess is the correct private key.// But other than that, the main problem with brain wallets, in Bitcoin at least, was the possibility of populating a huge hash table with a lot of addresses corresponding to relatively simple brain wallets, and just checking it for every new transaction. I think that that kind of attack is over with Monero.

Comment: You are of course able to use any KDF you want, but I'd recommend something like Cryptonight over SHA256 (or the Keccak on moneroaddress.org). My site doesn't currently have a user-facing text input for CN, but that's trivial to add (but I also don't want to necessarily encourage its use).

Comment: @Luigi: What is your site, if you don't mind saying it?

Comment: llcoins.net and pages there.

Comment: I made a [command-line utility](https://github.com/dan-da/subaddress-derive-xmr), written in php that understands monero mnemonics in multiple languages.  These language wordsets are pluggable, so it would be simple to create your own [wordset](https://github.com/dan-da/monero-mnemonic-php/tree/master/src/wordsets) and then generate a mnemonic from it.  Of course, you would need to use the same wordset when later decoding the mnemonic to retrieve your wallet seed.   I do not encourage actually doing this, but it is possible...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A brain wallet should always be created offline, preferably on a computer that will never touch the Internet once you decide to use it for a key generator. Make sure any JavaScripts you are using can be initiated offline.

Agree that there is a huge computing penalty for having to scan a blockchain for a given viewkey to identify associated stealth transaction deposits. A full refresh for a new wallet takes on the order of minutes on my computer with the current Monero Blockchain size.

Here is a quick example of using text commands to create a brain wallet:

`% echo "Brain farts really hurt this miser" | bx base16-encode | bx sha256`
**e812ff8072348464b3fe59f0324076bc9b1be3afb233d52303b04f19120389e3**

`% ./sc_reduce32 e812ff8072348464b3fe59f0324076bc9b1be3afb233d52303b04f19120389e3`
**f27b8d6b01c98293fa6acf06069644989a1be3afb233d52303b04f1912038903**

`% ./bytes_to_words f27b8d6b01c98293fa6acf06069644989a1be3afb233d52303b04f1912038903`
**etched segments dash puck rural furnished mice sapling sifting dime jigsaw alpine malady pebbles germs fleet puddle swagger azure react sovereign much worry zebra pebbles**

With either the normalized private spend key (after the sc_reduce32 completes) or the Electrum words you have the information to synthesize the following Monero address:

**44yo6exuJXtfmGzabRub8w6JkEcY6BjVEUkBmgheV5fEChMb5BD7HUWUPjuKVJ4C2Y11tf9y6DCJo2uAHts6E4EzJZX23fa**

FYSA - The sc_reduce32 command was created from a Monero function called sc_reduce32(). Similarly, the bytes_to_words command was created from a function called bytes_to_words().

Comment: Curious why you bother to base16-encode before sha256 hashing?

Comment: @skaht: I was just going ask why entering "Brain farts really hurt this miser" in an online SHA calculator gives a different result, but I think binaryFate might have just answered that; and now I second his question.// Other than that, this method seems to be what I suggested in the second paragraph of OP. Is that correct?

Comment: @skaht: I am sorry, but I feel more lost now: Are you saying that encoding base-16 is important, or optional? What is the advantage of appending 0a at the end of the hash? What makes it a *digitally signed* hash, and what key is doing the signing? Is this better for security?

Comment: @user141: Sorry for the confusion. The bitcoin explorer (bx) [base16-encode](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki/bx-base16-encode) command converts an ASCII string into a hexadecimal string that bx [sha256](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki/bx-sha256) command can use.  The "0a" that was tucked on after the base16 conversion was really an artifact of the echo command, not bx.  This example illustration should make the point very clear ```% bx base16-encode "abc"``` result is **616263** while ```% echo "abc" | bx base16-encode``` result is **6162630a**.

Comment: @user141: If the bx sha256 command accepts a hexadecimal number and the bx base16-encode command can convert a binary file to hexadecimal,  then the sha256 hash operation can operate on a binary file - not just a text file. Anyhow, I'll redo the example to get rid of the confusion within the comments.

Comment: ```% bx base16-encode "Brain farts really hurt this miser" | bx sha256```
**736f36409cd47b442177cea2fef4f7a6eb3727b45b887295948338d66f6c6523**

Comment: ```% ./sc_reduce32 736f36409cd47b442177cea2fef4f7a6eb3727b45b887295948338d66f6c6523```
**99c74a86670e5794743ddf5c41013a7deb3727b45b887295948338d66f6c6503**

Comment: ```% ./bytes_to_words 99c74a86670e5794743ddf5c41013a7deb3727b45b887295948338d66f6c6503```
**dice hefty unhappy fall obtains dagger auctions inexact sidekick evenings usher iguana axle faulty wrong spiders circle royal faked picked lifestyle click reef ribbon wrong**

Comment: The resulting address is: **42vk7Z6aZExXW7zG33ZbJweajY664Yx3rZtDTt6SFMENWrH7cCWN7mYU1yUmpzU48d8gfDznB4G54G8TDAspKXFq2YSVDWQ**

Comment: @skaht: So just to be sure: is it okay to just take sha256 of the passphrase and use that output as the hexadecimal seed?

Comment: @user141:  The bx sha256 implementation requires a hexadecimal string as input. Other sha256 hash mechanisms take ASCII text as input.  Nothing magical about the sha256.  For example, you could take a sha512 N times and feed that to a 256-bit Keccak hash performed M times and use the result a the seed.  The main point is the be consistent with your hashing sequence to recreate the effective 256-bit seed used.  The "echo" used in the example up top was always consistent with appending a "0a" to the end of the original string. What matters is process consistency for recreating a brain wallet.

Comment: Better to use `printf` instead of `echo` because it will not add a linefeed at the end.

Comment: Also, seems that you don't need `bx` at all. Just use `printf "Brain farts really hurt this miser" | sha256sum`

Answer (score 2):

> I remember reading somewhere, I think it was fluffypony mentioning one
>   could use for example words from a letter to a loved one seed for a
>   Monero wallet. But from playing with
>   https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html I realized that it is not
>   possible to enter just any text in the mnemonic seed;

I dont know what exactly he mentioned but I'd guess he meant hiding the mnemonic words into a poem created for the sole purpose of it, or something along those lines. Only words of the dictionary can be used, and you can see which those are if you look at the code [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/mnemonics/english.h#L54). There are exactly 1626 words. I wouldn't consider this approach safe because if anyone assumed you did hide some 25 words in a poem, he could compare the poem against the dictionary and isolate the words that belong to both the poem and the mnemonic dictionary. Then, he'd have a lot less guesswork to do in order to try and brute-force the correct mnemonic.

Regarding the second part of your question, I'd strongly advise against generating a seed by any other means than a good random number generator (even by rolling physical dice, for the extra paranoid - you need 100 rolls to get the 256bits of entropy). Our brain is horrible at producing true randomness, and hashing a passphrase has reduced entropy. If someone knew the scheme, he doesn't have to try and guess all possible seeds but can limit his guesses to only those that are the result of hashing a passphrase. This is exactly how many people lost bitcoins, by using weak passphrases for brain wallets.

IMO, the best way would be to just generate it randomly by using moneroaddress.org on an offline computer, and then remember the 25 words generated, or think of a good way to hide them.

While it is true that checking for balance takes a while, the point made by PyRulez is an important one. **If someone knows your address, he doesn't need to scan the blockchain anymore to verify that he made a correct guess.** But yes, just taking random guesses to try and find **any** address with a balance to loot, is way more expensive to do with monero than with bitcoin.

Edit: We could say that generating some long enough text with some personal info and then hashing it would be safe enough. Like "I bought my first yacht with Monero. It's 1983m long." where 1983 could be your birth year or something. That's 53 chars and probably not brute-forceable, but now that I've published this idea, anyone could try some number of variations of it for and see if he gets lucky.

Comment: Trying to memorize 25 words is asking to lose your coins IMO. The point of a brain wallet is taking something you *can* remember and producing a wallet from it. IIRC, the main problem with Bitcoin's brain wallets were the dragnet kind of attacks, in which someone would compile a very comprehensive list of simple brain wallets and just wait for someone to send money to it. If your brain wallet were relatively simple, but contained just a piece or more personal information, like your email, then it would be immune to such an attack, and would require instead that you'd be specifically targeted.

Comment: @user141 what your talking about is a salt, essentially.

Comment: @PyRulez: Yes. To be fair, that was something that increases security everywhere, including the Bitcoin brain wallet context.// The difficulty of checking those brain wallets for a balance (in an untargeted way) is a nice addition of stealth addresses.

Comment: Those are good points. Memorizing 25 words isn't easy, but with some practice and discipline it could be done. But yeah, you could write some text made up of few words which you'll easily remember, use capitalization and punctuation, add a little salt like your first phone number, e-mail or something and there you go. It's probably good enough, and for sure significantly less risky than in bitcoin. I'd still keep a physical backup somewhere safe.

Comment: Nonlinear salt is the spice of a secured brain wallet life.

Comment: @JollyMort: Regarding your point about it not being safe to hide the 25 words in a poem...if the correct order mnemonic seed was further encrypted with a password/passphrase, surely we are getting into safe territory there? To password brute force attack each possible order of 25 words (or 24 as we know the checksum goes at the end) blows my mind as to the numbers involved. You'd also have to scan each seed on the blockchain too which would add additional time/resources.

Comment: @TFI_Charmers The thing to keep in mind is that you might be likely to store your address somewhere. If the attacker can get that, he only needs to brute force that (then scan the chain after finding it). Brute-forcing the order of 24 words is a bit outside of current common resources, about 2^79 operations.

Comment: @Luigi So you are saying it is easier to "crack" a public Monero address than it is to find the correct order of 24 words that make up the mnemonic seed? Interesting if so. Are people trying that? That would make the Bitcoin rich list susceptible. What sort of resources would be required to brute force a Monero public address?

Comment: From where did you conclude that? Monero address usually have a little less than 256-bits of entropy, meaning 2^256 guesses vs. the number of permutations of 24 words (24! approx. = 2^79). I think the point made was, that if you have the unordered 24 words AND the address, you don't have to scan the blockchain. You'd just try the combinations until your resultant address matches the one you know to be the one with a balance.

Comment: I see. But checking my public address against the public addresses generated from each order of the words, would never match if my public address had been generated using a passphrase (from the correct mnemonic seed).

Sorry, I'm not technical so might be using the wrong terms.

Comment: So you'd be using the password to both dictate order AND encrypt/decrypt the mnemonic? The security would depend on your password strength (and possibly obscurity).

Comment: Encrypt the mnemonic and then shuffle the words, I take it. Then for each permutation you'd need also to bruteforce passwords, so 2^(79+71) possibilities if you use a 12 char password consisting of letters and numbers.